# Filter Pandas DataFrame by group with tag values

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I want to filter a DataFrame by group, since the following `nan` after **a**, are supposed to be **a** (this is something like a tag), and `nans` followed by **b**, are also **b**.
I have a short example:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'group1': ['a',nan,nan,nan,nan,'b',nan,nan,nan,nan],
                   'value1': [0.4,1.1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8.8],
                   'value2': [6.4, 6.9,7.1,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
                   })
```

My desired output would be:

```
In [3]: df[df.group1 == 'a']
Out[3]: 
  group1  value1  value2
0      a     0.4     6.4
1    NaN     1.1     6.9
2    NaN     2.0     7.1
3    NaN     3.0     8.0
4    NaN     4.0     9.0
```

I'll apreciate any hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ffill` to *forward-fill* the column:

```
>>> df[df['group1'].fillna(method='ffill') == 'a']
  group1  value1  value2
0      a     0.4     6.4
1    NaN     1.1     6.9
2    NaN     2.0     7.1
3    NaN     3.0     8.0
4    NaN     4.0     9.0
```

but, perhaps the better solution would be to forward-fill the column on the original data-frame:

```
>>> df['group1'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
>>> df[df['group1'] == 'a']
```